# How do I leave the Plains of Eidolon?

Tags: warframe

I have gotten lost out in the Plains of Eidolon.  How can I leave without losing progress?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option #1**: The **Ostron Tower**:

[image]

(in the background slightly right of the targeting reticle)

This tower will always be visible in some part of the skybox while out in the Plains, and will always lead you to the edge of Cetus (though not necessarily to the *door*).

**Option #2**: The map.

There is a setting in `esc->options->interface` called "Lock Map Rotation" (LMR).

Once back out of the options, press "M" to bring up the full-size map.

If LMR is **ON**:

- Cetus will always be in the center of the extreme south side of the map.

If LMR is **OFF**:

- Look for a large gray blob in the center of a side of the map.  This is Cetus.  It is possible that Cetus does not appear on the map where you are.  In this case, try to have your Warframe look around in different directions, as this will rotate the map and hopefully give you some idea of where Cetus is.

**Option #3:** Aborting.

Go to `esc->abort mission`.  Unlike most other missions in the game, here you get another menu asking if you wish to return to Cetus or to your orbiter.

**It is uncertain whether method #3 retains the drops from the session or not.  Use at your own risk!**

Comment: Aborting will keep rewards from any bounties you've done, but you'll lose everything else you've collected in the plains.

Comment: You may want to mention dropping a Loc-Pin at the doors.  This puts an icon on your HUD and has the added advantage of showing the way out when under-ground.